# Question on my Class implemention in C#

Tags: c#

Currently i have a class which has only properties

```
class MyEntity
{  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; } 
}
```

In my other class, I use to set the values like

```
MyEntity objEnt = new MyEntity();
objEnt.FirstName="abc";
objEnt.LastName = "edf";
```

The reason i have the class `MyEntity` with only properties is to ensure adherence.

Question here is, if this approach is correct? I can have multiple instances of `MyEntity`

Can i use Static Class for this? How can i use Generics in this?

BTW the implementation is in C#

Thanks in advance

Cheers,

Karthik

Comment: Whether it's correct depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve. What's your goal?

Comment: you have the class with only properties to ensure adherence to what?

Comment: as for plain POCO or DTO object this is just fine... for anything else it depends on the actual scenario

Comment: I have a db table and my class inserts data into this table. The fields are the properties of the class MyEntity in my example. [The table structure may not change]

Comment: and what do you need the class for... are you using some ORM tool to map the data from db to .net objects or are you writing the queries by hand?

Comment: Pleas look into my submit. Hope you will like it, because it uses generc singleton for interfaced entities ;)

Answer (score 1):

- You can't use a static class, as you have state. Static classes can only consist of static members.
- It's hard to see how you'd use generics here

Personally I prefer types to be immutable where possible - for example by giving `MyEntity` a constructor with two parameters, and removing the public setters from the properties. (Whether you keep private setters which you just don't use outside the constructor, or move to "proper" readonly fields and readonly properties is another choice.) However this mutable type *may* be absolutely fine for you - it's impossible to say without knowing what you're trying to do.

Note that you can use object initializers to make your initialization simpler, while you're using the mutable type:

```
MyEntity objEnt = new MyEntity { FirstName = "abc", LastName = "edf" };
```

(If you made the type immutable, you'd pass the values in the constructor. You could still use names via C# 4's "named arguments" feature, *if* you're using C# 4.)

Comment: @Umesh: I want to ensure that the data entered into my db

Comment: @Karthik K: You haven't shown anything related to the database at all, so we can't really tell whether that bit is sound.

Comment: I have a db table and my class inserts data into this table. The fields are the properties of the class MyEntity in my example. [The table structure may not change] I may have to insert multiple rows into the db. So i am thinking if i cold have a collections of the MyEntity object. The reason I want to have the column names in class MyEntity is that the table structure is fixed. Question is, if this approach is correct? Or Should i go for STRUCT? not sure if this is still vague.

Comment: Jon Skeet can change immutable objects.

Comment: @Karthik: I almost certainly *wouldn't* change to a struct. It's still not clear what design decisions you're really concerned about here... it all sounds fairly reasonable so far, but there's rather more to a data access layer than a class with two properties...

Comment: Firstly, you CAN have a singleton class, callable from static (i.e. as records manager). Immutability is a dream, not reality. See my posts. One of a methods is to use public read only interfacesed properties, and inplement them in class explicitly, and use write-only public properties fot object initialization (or just use construc\tor logic)

Comment: @Artur: It's not clear what you're responding to (particularly with reference to singletons, which hadn't been mentioned in this post before your comment)... or why you think that immutability can't be reality.

Comment: In my point of view, static class (mentioned above) is just a way to organaze the code (you can always use parameters to pass a "this" pointer). Think of extension methods. If so, you can always internally redirect static calls to singleton, saveng a state of you program

Comment: @Artur: Static classes are entirely inappropriate for *entities* though, as the whole point of an entity is to save state in an object. The class we've been given is clearly all about state. Static classes can only save state in a *global* way (well, per AppDomain). A static class would therefore be the wrong way to go here. But by all means add an answer showing how you'd model the data using a static class...

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers and feedback. The problem i think i have is that i am not trying to see if my design is better. I had explained just a minor part of what i am doing. I was trying my best to explain this part. I have an abstract class deriving this abstract class. Other supporting classes are the MyEntity class which i had mentioned above. I use these supporting classes in my derived class. This supporting class is what brought me to ask this question. Question i had was just to have entities for setting and getting the values, i was thinking if Static class / class /or struct

Answer (score 1):

As already said it depends from your needs.
Just to note that you can't use static class as you want to have multiple instances and also there can be issues with synchronization while access from multiple threads.

As for generics ... whats for you need it here ?

Answer (score 0):

I had an answer half typed, but then Jon answered so my answer in its current form became pointless....

I will offer a counterpoint on Jon's answer though. Think carefully before using immutable objects - they are good from some perspectives, but you will quickly run into trouble if using them for binding to *editable* fields, or if serializing them (either to storage or for transferring, ie WCF web service calls).

Comment: Trying to make immutable types editable certainly causes a problem :) There are definitely ways of using immutable types with serialization - it's just that the built-in serializers tend to make it difficult :( Protocol buffers is designed around immutable types, as an example...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty use of generics for your unspecified DTO I am assuming.

```
class MyEntity<T>
{
   public T value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not a valid replacement for his original class, which had two properties. Also, it's very hard to see the usefulness of this.